# transfer funds from regtest to real testnet

Tags: testnet, regtest

is there a way to transfer tBTC from regtest to a real testnet wallet?

I know how to create a regtest, but not (if is possible) how to transfer to testnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. These are two (or more) different networks with different transactions history.

Comment: bro just did double spend on regtest: https://gist.github.com/System-Glitch/cb4e87bf1ae3fec9925725bb3ebe223a